# Summernote codeview text overflow wrap

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, summernote

I use summernote and it's codeview. My problem is that if the string is to long, it goes into infinity. I would like to overflow wrap it. So I don't need to scroll horizontally.

Any cluses?

Here is my initiation code.

```
    var summernote = $('#description').summernote({
        height: 1000,                 // set editor height
        minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
        maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor
        maxWidth: 100,             // set maximum width of editor
        toolbar: [
          ['style', ['style']],
          ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
          // ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'clear']],
          ['color', ['color']],
          ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
          ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'hr']],
          ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],   // remove codeview button
          ['help', ['help']]
        ],
        codemirror: {
          mode: 'text/html',
          htmlMode: true,
          lineNumbers: true,
          theme: 'monokai'
        },
        callbacks: {
          onInit: function() {
            console.log('Summernote is launched');
            $(this).summernote('codeview.activate');
            $('#title').focus();
          }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
lineWrapping: true,
```

after  lineNumbers: true,
works for me